# How to properly use a shut pin in audio connector to prevent floating pins when disconnected

Tags: audio, schematics, pullup, pulldown

I'd like to use this [RCA jack](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/PJRAN1X1U01X.pdf) in a project that detects roughly the volume level on an RCA audio source. The circuit filters out the DC line voltage, amplifies it with a PNP transistor and then shifts the AC audio signal ~+2.5V so an Arduino can read it.

In my circuit I'm measuring the signal on the tip and just pulling the sleeve to ground.

I've read this [great post over at CUI](https://www.cui.com/blog/understanding-audio-jack-switches-and-schematics) and understand that the shunt (pin 3) acts like a normally closed switch between the sleeve and the shunt.

What's the appropriate way to prevent the this from floating and picking up noise when there's no source plugged in? I gather that it's normal to either put a pull-up or pull-down resistor on this type of shunt. I'm just not sure what would be correct here.

For reference, [I'm using this circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhTvy.png) as an amplifier with a voltage divider and .1pF cap to between the amplifier circuit and the arduino.

[image: RCA Jack w/ 1-Tip, 2-Sleeve, 3-Shunt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connect pin 3 to pin 1. That way, when the input signal is disconnected pin 2 will be grounded and there will be no noise pickup.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the simple answer is just too obvious to see right away.